# Add data to JSON for dates which are not there

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date, foreach

I use fullcalendar.io and I need to put prices on all dates beetween. Some prices I get from database but some fixed which are not in database I need to create at frontend so with javascript (I think that will be faster and I dont fill database with stupid fixed data, becouse just dates will be different)

First I have start and end date:

```
var period_start = new Date('2016-02-04 15:18:46');
var period_end = new Date('2016-11-04 15:18:46');
```

Also I get from database this JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 5,
    "user_id": 1,
    "article_id": 5,
    "price": 78,
    "comment": "",
    "created_at": "2016-02-04 18:33:41",
    "updated_at": "2016-02-04 18:33:41",
    "key": "xLetirBT8wfrTNoQgqkeBUu8ebmZld",
    "title": "",
    "start": "2016-03-25 15:18:46"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "user_id": 1,
    "article_id": 5,
    "price": 55,
    "comment": "",
    "created_at": "2016-02-04 18:33:33",
    "updated_at": "2016-02-04 18:33:33",
    "key": "xLetirBT8wfrTNoQgqkeBUu8ebmZld",
    "title": "",
    "start": "2016-03-15 15:18:46"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "user_id": 1,
    "article_id": 5,
    "price": 35,
    "comment": "",
    "created_at": "2016-02-04 18:33:25",
    "updated_at": "2016-02-04 18:33:25",
    "key": "xLetirBT8wfrTNoQgqkeBUu8ebmZld",
    "title": "",
    "start": "2016-03-07 15:18:46"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 1,
    "article_id": 5,
    "price": 22,
    "comment": "dd",
    "created_at": "2016-03-04 15:20:36",
    "updated_at": "2016-02-04 15:20:36",
    "key": "xLetirBT8wfrTNoQgqkeBUu8ebmZld",
    "title": "drugi",
    "start": "2016-03-05 15:18:46"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "article_id": 5,
    "price": 44,
    "comment": "gg",
    "created_at": "2016-05-04 15:18:46",
    "updated_at": "2016-02-04 15:18:46",
    "key": "xLetirBT8wfrTNoQgqkeBUu8ebmZld",
    "title": "prvi",
    "start": "2016-02-04 15:18:46"
  }
]
```

Now I want to fill this JSON with dates which are not in JSON file so all dates between period_start and period_end who missing...

so etc. I have in JSON - start: 2016-02-05 but missing other dates...

**How to put empty dates into JSON and just change the date - `start` ?**

Also if you have some better solution please tell me, I think that the best is to fill empty dates at frontend with javascript-jquery...

Comment: Just push your non-db entries onto the array?

Comment: Ok but How to create loop for dates beetween period_start and period_end ? Can you please write as answer ?

Comment: Note that "2016-02-04 15:18:46" is not a format required to be supported by ECMA-262 and is not supported by even some of the most recent versions of popular browsers in use. Date strings should always be manually parsed (or use a library, but a parse function is trivial). You should at least use a standards compliant date string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add a day to the start date until you get to the end date to populate an array, then replace the dates for the data you have. You could also check if you have a date in the db data as you populate, but this was quick and dirty and I wanted to show *map* and *filter*...

```
// declare variables
var period_start = new Date('2016-02-04 15:18:46'),
    period_end = new Date('2016-11-04 15:18:46'),
    current_date = period_start,
    array_of_all_dates = [];

// Create a populated array of dates
while (current_day.getTime() <= period_end.getTime()) {
    array_of_all_dates.push(current_date);
    current_date = new Date(+current_date);
    current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() + 1);
}

// Now loop over the array of populated dates and mutate, so something like
array_of_all_dates = array_of_all_dates.map(function (date) {
    var found_in_db = db_data.filter(function (db_data) {
        return new Date(db_data.start).getTime() === date.getTime(); // You need to do this comparison better!
    });
    if (found_in_db.length > 0) {
        return found_in_db[0];
    }
    var new_object = {
        a_property: 'some_default_value',
        start: date
    };
    return new_object;

});
```

I'm sure this could be done better, but technique is ok if you ignore the time parts and significantly improve the date comparison.

You should probably look into array operations if you don't recognise *filter* and *map*.

I've added some extra into the snippet for the purposes of looking at the objects.

```js
var addToList = function (text) {
  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(text);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
};




//var db_data = [{"start": "2016-05-04T15:18:46", "title": "FOUND"}, {"start": "2016-06-04T15:18:46", "title": "FOUND ME TOO"}];
var db_data = [
  {
    "id": 5,
    "user_id": 1,
    "article_id": 5,
    "price": 78,
    "comment": "",
    "created_at": "2016-02-04 18:33:41",
    "updated_at": "2016-02-04 18:33:41",
    "key": "xLetirBT8wfrTNoQgqkeBUu8ebmZld",
    "title": "",
    "start": "2016-03-25 15:18:46"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "user_id": 1,
    "article_id": 5,
    "price": 55,
    "comment": "",
    "created_at": "2016-02-04 18:33:33",
    "updated_at": "2016-02-04 18:33:33",
    "key": "xLetirBT8wfrTNoQgqkeBUu8ebmZld",
    "title": "",
    "start": "2016-03-15 15:18:46"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "user_id": 1,
    "article_id": 5,
    "price": 35,
    "comment": "",
    "created_at": "2016-02-04 18:33:25",
    "updated_at": "2016-02-04 18:33:25",
    "key": "xLetirBT8wfrTNoQgqkeBUu8ebmZld",
    "title": "",
    "start": "2016-03-07 15:18:46"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 1,
    "article_id": 5,
    "price": 22,
    "comment": "dd",
    "created_at": "2016-03-04 15:20:36",
    "updated_at": "2016-02-04 15:20:36",
    "key": "xLetirBT8wfrTNoQgqkeBUu8ebmZld",
    "title": "drugi",
    "start": "2016-03-05 15:18:46"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "article_id": 5,
    "price": 44,
    "comment": "gg",
    "created_at": "2016-05-04 15:18:46",
    "updated_at": "2016-02-04 15:18:46",
    "key": "xLetirBT8wfrTNoQgqkeBUu8ebmZld",
    "title": "prvi",
    "start": "2016-02-04 15:18:46"
  }
];

// declare variables
var period_start = new Date('2016-02-04T15:18:46'),
    period_end = new Date('2016-11-04T15:18:46'),
    current_date = period_start,
    array_of_all_dates = [];

// Create a populated array of dates
while (current_date.getTime() <= period_end.getTime()) {
  array_of_all_dates.push(current_date);
  current_date = new Date(+current_date);
  current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() + 1);
}

// Now loop over the array of populated dates and mutate, so something like
array_of_all_dates = array_of_all_dates.map(function (date) {
  var found_in_db = db_data.filter(function (db_data) {
    return new Date(db_data.start.replace(" ", "T")).getTime() === date.getTime(); // You need to do this comparison better!
  });
  if (found_in_db.length > 0) {
    return found_in_db[0];
  }
  var new_object = {
    a_property: 'some_default_value',
    start: date
  };
  console.log(new_object);
  return new_object;

});

// Display something
array_of_all_dates.forEach(function (date_object) {
  addToList(JSON.stringify(date_object));
});
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
</ul>
```

Comment: `current_day.getTime() <= period_end.getTime()` can be `current_day <= period_end`, and `new Date(date)` should probably be `new Date(current_date)`. But you don't need the temporary *new_current_date*, just do `current_date = new Date(+current_date)` and a new Date instance is assigned.

Comment: @RobG Can you please write this as answer - as example on jsfiddle ?

Comment: If the performance will b better if I use ARRAY ? instead JSON?

Comment: @MonkeyBusiness JSON is a transport format to send data from the server and so it isn't a question of whether you use Array or JSON as you put it. JSON may contain an array, which is what your question shows.

Comment: Thanks, I need around from 200-300 days so I think that loop time cant be a problem... This works good. Thanks again... Also here you say:         return new Date(db_data.start).getTime() === date.getTime(); // You need to do this comparison better!
 BUT HOW I CAN DO THIS ?

Comment: Sorry but when I try to implement code into mine I get: http://imgur.com/SXZqzCO and Uncaught ReferenceError: addToList is not defined... WHY?

Comment: Can you please here write as a function which will return JSON formated data not html... https://jsfiddle.net/w8dm8o75/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w8dm8o75/1/ - Here I create a function fullJSON which must return me JSON of all data...

Comment: HELP! HELP! how to put it in one function which will return me json?

Comment: @MonkeyBusiness I've updated your fiddle to be a function: https://jsfiddle.net/w8dm8o75/2/

Comment: @MonkeyBusiness With regards to your question about the date comparison: this function will fail to lookup from the db_data object if the time portion (which happens to be _15:18:46_ on all your objects) doesn't match exactly, you probably want to look if the date is the same and ignore the time.

Comment: Something like this: var db_data_date = new Date(db_data.start.replace(" ", "T"));
        return db_data_date.getFullYear() === date.getFullYear() &&
            db_data_date.getMonth() === date.getMonth() &&
                db_data_date.getDay() === date.getDay();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102726/discussion-between-monkeybusiness-and-neil-twist).